# Why does var evaluate to System.Object in "foreach (var row in table.Rows)"?

Tags: c#, ado.net

When I enter this `foreach` statement...

```
foreach (var row in table.Rows)
```

...the tooltip for var says `class System.Object`

I'm confused why it's not `class System.Data.DataRow`.

(In case you're wondering, yes, I have `using System.Data` at the top of my code file.)

---

If I declare the type explicitly, as in...

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
```

...it works fine with no errors.

---

Also if I do...

```
var numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
foreach (var number in numbers)
```

...var evaluates to `struct System.Int32`. So, the problem is not that `var` doesn't work in a `foreach` clause.

---

So, there's something strange about `DataRowCollection` where the items don't automatically evaluate to `DataRow`. But I can't figure out what it is. Does anyone have an explanation?

---

**Update**

I was really torn which answer to mark (Codeka and Oliver)...In the end, I decided to mark Codeka's because it truly answers my question, but Oliver answers the question I should have been asking :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

That's because the [DataRowCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcollection%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class only implements the non-generic version of `IEnumerable`. So the compiler doesn't know what the type of the variable is.

By explicitly putting the type in there, you basically tell the compiler to generate an explicit cast from `object` to `DataRow`.

This is a problem you'll find with many of the collections and classes added back in the .NET 1.x days, before generics were available.

Answer (score 12):

While codeka is right, there exists some other methods to get more convenience into this `DataTable` and `DataRow`stuff.

With .Net 3.5 you can add the assembly `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`.

It contains some extension functions like `AsEnumerable(this System.Data.DataTable)` or `Field<T>(this System.Data.DataRow, int)` with it you can call it within a foreach loop and cast the column directly into the proper type:

```
int columnIndex = 2;

foreach(var row in MyDataTable.AsEnumerable())
{
    var content = row.Field<double>(columnIndex);
}
```