# Implicit typing on ListItemCollection not possible using foreach, but possible with for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, implicit

A ListBox control has an `Items` property of type [ListItemCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.aspx).

I sort of understand why I can't write

```
foreach (var item in ShipperListBox.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected) count++;
}
```

But instead have to write

```
foreach (ListItem item in ShipperListBox.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected) count++;
}
```

It has to do with `ListItemCollection` implementing `IEnumerable` and not `IEnumerable<ListItem>` (as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786727/why-does-var-evaluate-to-system-object-in-foreach-var-row-in-table-rows?lq=1)).

But what I don't get is why the following is no problem.

```
for (int i = 0; i < ListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (ListBox1.Items[i].Selected) count++;
}
```

What part of ListItemCollection is making it clear to the compiler that `ListBox.Items[i]` is of type `ListItem`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `ListItemCollection` implements an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.item.aspx) that returns a `ListItem`.

This is separate from `IEnumerable`.

Comment: If the indexer would be used it would work with var since the indexer does return ListItem. Please see the link of my answer how foreach is expanded by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

This is part of what `.OfType<ListItem>()` and `.Cast<ListItem>()` explicitly exist for:

> The Cast(IEnumerable) method enables the standard query operators to be invoked on non-generic collections by supplying the necessary type information. For example, ArrayList does not implement IEnumerable, but by calling Cast(IEnumerable) on the ArrayList object, the standard query operators can then be used to query the sequence. [(source)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx)

So you can write

```
foreach (var item in ShipperListBox.Items.OfType<ListItem>())
{
    if (item.Selected) count++;
}
```

I couldn't tell you why, though.

Comment: It because some of these classes existed in the pre-generics days of C#.

Comment: I figured it was something like that.

Comment: I suppose `.Cast<ListItem>()` would be the same as writing `foreach (ListItem item in ShipperListBox.Items`? Using `OfType<ListItem>()` would make 100% sure I can only get objects of type ListItem, right? So that would be the safest way. In case of a ListItemCollection though I don't think I could ever get something other than `ListItem`, so just writing `foreach (ListItem item...` would be the best.

Comment: Yeah, they all do effectively the same thing, with `OfType` being nominally safer, although I don't think you could ever make that matter.  Explicitly typing the variable is definitely the best way in this case.

Answer (score 0):

ListItemCollection.GetEnumerator does return an enumerator which was used since .NET 1.0 which does return object as value. The [foreach pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/06/30/following-the-pattern.aspx) (as Eric Lippert does explain in much greater detail) requires an Enumerator returned by the object via the GetEnumerator method.

When you use var the compiler infers the type of you loop variable as object since Current of the Enumerator does return only an object.

```
public interface IEnumerator
{
    bool MoveNext();
    object Current { get; }
    void Reset();
}
```

But when you use `foreach(ListItem item in xxx)` ... the compiler does add a cast to ListItem from object automatically for you. You can try it out when you do a foreach(string str in new object[] { "str", 1 }) which will result in an InvalidCastException. There is no magic going with the `var` keyword. It simply does infer the type without doing any extra magic.

When you expect a `ListItem` in your loop you should write it out clearly. From the method signature of the enumerator it is not clear what objects it will return. You have to tell the compiler which types you expect. One more reason to not use the var keyword since the readers of your code will also not be able to deduce the type of your looping variable as well.