# Why ListItem must be declared explicitly in foreach C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm confused as to why this code would not compile if `listControl` is a ListControl object such as a DropDownList:

```
foreach (var item in listControl.Items) {
    item.Value = string.empty;
}
```

The compiler considers `item` to be of type `object`. It works if I replace `var` with `ListItem`, declaring the variable explicitly. The `Items` property is a `ListItemCollection`, which implements `IEnumerable`. Shouldn't the compiler be able to tell that the objects in the collection are of type `ListItem`?

Comment: So your question already contains answer - as you've noted [ListItemCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) implements `IEnumerable` - iteration over collection of `object`, and not `IEnumerable<ListItem>`... Consider to clarify what exactly you need explanation for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a strange behavior since, as you point out, `ListItemCollection` is a collection of `ListItem`s. This appears related to the fact that this was implemented before C# supported generics. And so it implements `IEnumerable` instead of `IEnumerable<ListItem>`, and isn't able to determine the correct type.

I suggest rewriting your loop this way:

```
foreach (ListItem item in listControl.Items) {
    item.Value = string.empty;
}
```

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786727/why-does-var-evaluate-to-system-object-in-foreach-var-row-in-table-rows?lq=1) for additional information.

Comment: The MSDN documentation seems to suggest that a ListItemCollection only contains ListItems: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: "this was implemented before C# supported generics" that satisfactorily answers my question of "why", though I'm not happy about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Compiler can't tell that to you at compile time because the items are object. It will compile with any type, for example if you use

```
foreach(int item in collection)
```

it will compile, because casting from object to int is valid, but it will throw an exception at runtime because the types are not compatible.

Comment: Yes but since this particular type of collection (ListItemCollection) can only contain ListItems, any declaration other than ListItem or object will throw a runtime exception... the compiler CAN safely assume the type (like it does for any other collection) because there is only one type possible.

Comment: @kad81 No it cant because the place the compiler checks is the return type of `GetEnumerator()`, ListItemCollection only implements [`IEnumerator GetEnumerator()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitemcollection.getenumerator(v=vs.110).aspx) not `IEnumerator<ListItem> GetEnumerator()`  so the compiler does not have enough information at compile time to determine the type.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain You nailed it. `ListItemCollection` does not implement the generic version. Nice.

Comment: @kad81 because `ListItemCollection` implements non-generic `IEnumerable` there is no guarantee that it will return `ListItems`. Yes the implementation or documentation can guarantee that to you but compiler can't.For example you can implement `IEnumerable` for your class and return items of different types, because the interface is not generic.

Answer (score 1):

## Original Question

> The Items property is a ListItemCollection, which implements IEnumerable. Shouldn't the compiler be able to tell that the objects in the collection are of type ListItem?

## Short Answer

**No.** The compile-time type is `object` because that's the compile-time type of `IEnumerator.Current`. The `var` keyword is still statically typed! If `ListItemCollection` implemented `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `IEnumerable`, then the compiler would know more.

## More Details

[From the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItemCollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> ... a System.Collections.IEnumerator [is] used to get items from the collection.

When you use a `foreach` loop, you're implicitly using the IEnumerator interface. So, when you access each item, the `Current` property [returns an object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerator.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) even though it's a `ListItem` underneath at run-time.

Importantly, the `var` keyword is still static, so you might as well have written the following code. Would you expect the compiler to figure out this:

```
foreach (var item in (object)listControl.Items) {
    item.Value = string.empty;
}
```

Your `var` is a statically-typed `object`. If you want the run-time to figure out that it's a ListItem, then you have to use `dynamic` instead of `var`.